# unable to inspect docker to postgres traffic in the same host

Tags: docker, tcpdump

There's a docker web application installed in a linux host, and it works fine. I know this docker instance is connecting to postgres database with port 5432, and I'm trying to understand the traffic between docker and postgres database by logging into the linux host.

When I ran `docker ps` I only saw the web application, I don't see any docker instance for postgres.

I saw there are postgres process running with `ps -ef | grep postgres` but I'm unable to see port 5432 is listening with `netstat -an | grep 5432`

The interesting part is `/usr/lib/postgresql` folder doesn't even exist per the output below.

`$ ps -ef | grep postgres ubuntu    2622  2555  0 16:09 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main  -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf ubuntu    3249  2622  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: checkpointer process    ubuntu    3250  2622  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: writer process    ubuntu    3251  2622  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: wal writer process    ubuntu    3252  2622  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: autovacuum launcher process    ubuntu    3253  2622  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: stats collector process    ubuntu    3254  2622  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: bgworker: logical replication launcher    ubuntu    3821  2622  0 16:10 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: openvino workbench 127.0.0.1(35548) idle`

I ran `sudo tcpdump -i docker0 'port 5432'` but I'm unable to see any traffic.

Tracing PPID of postgres PID:

```
PID CMD
28691 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
  PID CMD
28639 bash /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/tools/workbench/docker-entrypoint.sh
  PID CMD
28619 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/a129c1514c181b85e9d75d8b20d909b1540f94c39792e370ab82918a681cbcb7 -address /run/contain
  PID CMD
 5198 /usr/bin/containerd
  PID CMD
    1 /lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 38
```

Any ideas? Please advise.
Thanks!!

Comment: Try running `netstat -tapn | grep 5432` inside the container to see to which PostgreSQL instance it's pointed to.

Comment: It doesn't return anything.

Comment: That's very odd. Maybe the PostgreSQL is running inside the web container? You can find out where the PostgreSQL instance is running by checking it's [parent pid](https://gist.github.com/gkawamoto/094101d95f8e2cf8a11927f6e56f439f)

Comment: I have updated the post with the process id tracing. It looks like `28619 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/a129c1514c181b85e9d75d8b20d909b1540f94c39792e370ab82918a681cbcb7 -address /run/contain` is the process running postgresql, so postgresql is running inside the docker?

Comment: Is there a way I can connect to the database? I've installed postgresql client and trying....

Comment: That's correct. The PostgreSQL is running inside the `a129c1514c` container. You can connect to it and install `tcpdump` directly on the container, or connect using the `psql` cli that's usually installed along the DB.

Comment: `openvino@869ed3102010:/opt/intel/openvino_2020.4.287/deployment_tools/tools/workbench$ psql
psql: FATAL:  database "openvino" does not exist`

Comment: We're getting somewhere haha. Try `psql -l` to list the databases available and then `psql <your-db>` to connect to the database you want.

Comment: I think I did it wrong. I shouldn't install tcpdump as a docker image, I should install tcpdump after bashing into the web container. correct?

Comment: That’s right! The container is it’s own owner, containing its own namespace, pid tree, network and filesystem. Therefore, if you wish to debug it, you should install the debug tools inside it (bashing into it)